# Python cx_Freeze error “No module named 'cx_Freeze.util'

Tags: python, module

I am running a very simple code to test cx_Freeze module but when running appears the error above. 
I am using Python 3.5 and the new version (5.0) of cx_Freeze.

CODE:
Calling cx_Freeze: 
from cx_Freeze import setup 
Executable setup( name = "Prueba", version = "0.1", description = "My application!" 
executables = [Executable("pruebas.py")])

pruebas.py: text='Hello' print(text)

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the code you're using.

Comment: Calling cx_Freeze:
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(  name = "Prueba",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "My application!",
        executables = [Executable("pruebas.py")])
///////
pruebas.py:
text='Hello'
print(text)

Answer (score 0):

there is 2 type cx_freeze installation package: amd64 or win32
Make sure that what you have is the good version. I firstly installed the version amd64,but apperently my python version is 32bits. So i met the same pb as yours. Try another one, maybe you can success.